# how to stay in the same route in python flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have added a route to the flask app, but it seems I can't get the results on the browser:

```
# A very simple Flask Hello World app for you to get started with...
#
from flask import Flask, request

from processing import do_calc_melting2


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route("/melting2", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_page_melting():
    errors = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        number1 = None
        number2 = None
        number3 = None
        try:
            number1 = float(request.form["number1"])
        except:
            errors += "<p>{!r} is not a number.</p>\n".format(request.form["number1"])
        try:
            number2 = float(request.form["number2"])
        except:
            errors += "<p>{!r} is not a number.</p>\n".format(request.form["number2"])
        try:
            number3 = float(request.form["number3"])
        except:
            errors += "<p>{!r} is not a number.</p>\n".format(request.form["number3"])
        if number1 is not None and number2 is not None and number3 is not None:
            result = do_calc_melting2(number1, number2, number3)
            return '''
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <p>The result is {result}</p>
                        <p><a href="/melting2">Click here to calculate again</a>
                    </body>
                </html>
            '''.format(result)
    return '''
        <html>
                <form method="post" action=".">
                    <p><p>Number 1</p><input name="number1" /></p>
                    <p><p>Number 2</p><input name="number2" /></p>
                    <p><p>Number 3</p><input name="number3" /></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Do calculation" /></p>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    '''.format(errors=errors)
```

When I use @app.route("/") everything works just fine, but when I use different route then the post part works, then it jumps to "/" route.

Comment: This sounds a bit like you did not understand the relation between the URL in the browser and the route in Flask.

Comment: It could be true. I only need to generate a few numbers based on user inputs. This is a frankenstein code that I put together from different places. So how can it be done?

Comment: Take a tutorial.

Comment: Your specification of the action attribute causes the form to be sent to the index route. If you don't intend this, remove the attribute and the form will be sent to the same route that the form originated from.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change (or fully remove) the `action` attribute in your form:

```
from flask import Flask, request

from processing import do_calc_melting2


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route("/melting2", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_page_melting():
    errors = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        number1 = None
        number2 = None
        number3 = None
        try:
            number1 = float(request.form["number1"])
        except:
            errors += "<p>{!r} is not a number.</p>\n".format(request.form["number1"])
        try:
            number2 = float(request.form["number2"])
        except:
            errors += "<p>{!r} is not a number.</p>\n".format(request.form["number2"])
        try:
            number3 = float(request.form["number3"])
        except:
            errors += "<p>{!r} is not a number.</p>\n".format(request.form["number3"])
        if number1 is not None and number2 is not None and number3 is not None:
            result = do_calc_melting2(number1, number2, number3)
            return '''
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <p>The result is {result}</p>
                        <p><a href="/melting2">Click here to calculate again</a>
                    </body>
                </html>
            '''.format(result)
    return '''
        <html>
                <form method="post" action="/melting2">
                    <p><p>Number 1</p><input name="number1" /></p>
                    <p><p>Number 2</p><input name="number2" /></p>
                    <p><p>Number 3</p><input name="number3" /></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Do calculation" /></p>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    '''.format(errors=errors)
```

What was happening before was that the form directed you to the home page when you submitted it (`action="."`). Now that the URL in the form is changed to `/melting2`, all of your functionality will work.